# Angular + d3.js: Data binding with SVG text attr?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm working on a visualization that involves updating a text element that appear inside of a circle. Something like:

```
<g>
    <circle></circle>
    <text>My text that needs updating</text>
</g>
```

Along with this small visual is a d3 brush being used as a slider. On brush/brushend, I need to `<text>Update the text here</text>`, based on data associated with a time scale along the slider's x-axis.

I have two Angular directives. One that contains the circle, the other that is the slider. In my slider directive I'm calling:

`$rootScope.$emit('brushing');` and setting a rootScope variable according to my data, `$rootScope.myNewValue = newValue;` as sliding occurs

Then I'm listening for this in my other directive, and updating the text.attr to be the rootScope var:

`$rootScope.$on('brushing', function () {
    myText.text($rootScope.myNewValue);
});`

Where:

```
var myText = svg.append('text')
    .text('I'm trying to update this text..');
```

... in the d3 portion of the code

Doing things this way seems to work, but I'm wondering if there is a way to bind the data directly when initializing myText:

```
var myText = svg.append('text)
    .text($rootScope.myNewValue);
```

So that the value updates directly without having to $emit and listen. I've tried `scope.$apply` in the directive but that seems to have no effect.

Has anyone encountered a similar scenario when using d3 with Angular?

Comment: Have you tried just using angular binding to bind the text to a variable? Here is a good article on using SVG directly with angular: http://alexandros.resin.io/angular-d3-svg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap up the D3JS code in a directive then use a property that is passed in and watch it to see if it changes to update the D3JS code accordingly (your saving a reference to the svg text is still probably the best bet).  For an example see my directive below where I use val to update the data used in a bar chart display (note I didn't deal with transitions here yet, and the codes a bit of a mess but hopefully you see the general point)

```
directive('barChart', function ( /* dependencies */ ) {
  // define constants and helpers used for the directive

  var width = 600,
    height = 80;

  return {
    restrict: 'E', // the directive can be invoked only by using <bar-chart></bar-chart> tag in the template
    scope: { // attributes bound to the scope of the directive
      val: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      // initialization, done once per my-directive tag in template. If my-directive is within an
      // ng-repeat-ed template then it will be called every time ngRepeat creates a new copy of the template.

      // set up initial svg object
      var vis = d3.select(element[0])
        .append("svg")
          .attr("class", "chart")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);


      // whenever the bound 'exp' expression changes, execute this 
      scope.$watch('val', function (newVal, oldVal) {

        // clear the elements inside of the directive
        vis.selectAll('*').remove();
        vis.attr("height", newVal.length*22);

        // if 'val' is undefined, exit
        if (!newVal) {
          return;
        }
        var totalDataSetSize = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < newVal.length; i++) {
          totalDataSetSize += newVal[i].data.length
        };

        function calcBarWidth(d) {
          return (totalDataSetSize==0)?0:d.data.length/totalDataSetSize*420;
        }

        vis.selectAll("rect")
            .data(newVal)
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i*20; })
            .attr("width", calcBarWidth)
            .attr("height", function(d) {return 20});

        vis.selectAll("text")
            .data(newVal)
          .enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return calcBarWidth(d)+10})
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return (i+1)*20; })
            .attr("dy", "-.3em") // vertical-align: middle
            .style("font-size", ".7em")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("text-anchor", "beginning") // text-align: right
            .text(function(d,i){ return d.data.length.toString() + "  " + d.label})

      },true);
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This will probably work and I'll give it a try. I didn't think about setting up a watch. I'm currently passing in the value through an attr rather than a property of the isolate scope but I would anticipate similar results.

Comment: Yeah I think this will work for you, let me know if there's some issue as I plan to use this going forward :)

Comment: Will do. Haven't had a chance to try it out yet but will be back in the code this afternoon and will post an update.

Comment: We changed the approach of our application just slightly. What we are now doing is manipulating our slider, sending a XHR request based on the positioning, then updating our UI. However, this solution works for the new case and our previous approach. Thanks!