# D3 and two-way data binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, d3.js

I am interested in the current best practices and solutions for using the [data driven documents](http://d3js.org/) library with two-way `AJAX` data bindings. More specifically I am wondering how [d3](http://d3js.org/) should be best integrated with libs supporting two-way data bindings such as [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).

The obvious conflicts that arise stem from the fact that [d3](http://d3js.org/) and the `AJAX` libs are both inserting data to the `DOM`, which basically means that one has to wrap the other.

Comment: If I manipulate the D3 data source, the rendered UI should update accordingly (it doesn't).  I too would like to know how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

## About Data on DOM

You were worried about the data inserted to the DOM. This are some of the properties added:

- D3js: `__data__`, `__onmouseover.force`, `__onmouseout.force`, `__onmousedown.drag`, `__ontouchstart.drag`, `__onmousedown`
- AngularJS: `value`, `type`, `version`, `align`, `ng339`

So there's no colisions and no need to wrap one into another. You can test this using `Object.keys(SOME_DOM_ELEMENT);` and `Object.keys(SOME_DOM_ELEMENT.__proto__);`

## About Implementation

### Pure javascript

This is how you assign data to D3js:

```
d3selector.data( myNameSpace.myDataObject );
```

And this is my data binding approach using watch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

```
d3selector
myNameSpace.watch('myDataObject', function (id, oldval, newval) {
    d3selector.data( newval );
    return newval;
});
```

This way, everytime you change `myNameSpace.myDataObject` the data used by D3js will be updated too. But this will only work on Firefox.

### AngularJS

There's an answer in this question [Angular + d3.js: Data binding with SVG text attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482101/angular-d3-js-data-binding-with-svg-text-attr?rq=1) that explains how to do it using $watch.

Is similar to the Firefox watch:

```
directive('myDirective', function ( /* dependencies */ ) {

    // Imagine your $scope has myDataObject
    $scope.$watch('myDataObject', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        d3selector.data(newVal);
    });

}
```

Now everytime you change `myDataObject` in the `$scope` the data of D3js will be updated too.

### More info

Here is an example of *two way data binding* using [polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/polymer/info): http://bl.ocks.org/psealock/a4f1e24535f0353d91ea you can test it here: http://bl.ocks.org/psealock/raw/a4f1e24535f0353d91ea/

As you can see in `refreshChart` the binding is not really being used. Instead, on the event triggered when the data changes, D3js loads the new data:

```
this.g.data(this.pie(this.data));
```

D3js is not prepared to listen for changes on the data, unless you use the `data` method. That's why the already rendered data will not change.

If in the future data bindings were implemented, I guess there will be a new method on `selection`:

> selection.update - return placeholders for updated elements.

similar to the current `enter` and `exit`:

> selection.enter - returns placeholders for missing elements.
>
> selection.exit - returns elements that are no longer needed.

removing the need to create refresh functions.